# Type or namespace is not found Error when deploying the website

Tags: asp.net, sisodb

the website works nice on local system but when I deploy it , an exception throws that :

```
CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ISisoDatabase' does not exist in the namespace 'SisoDb' (are you missing an assembly reference?) ?
```

it's a shared host by the way .

any idea why this is happening ?

**Edit** : I used Web Project instead of WebSite and this error is gone but another exception is thrown :

```
Could not load file or assembly 'SisoDb, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
```

**solved :** the problem was the **ftp client** I used to upload dlls . it sounds ftp corrupted the dlls. when I added assemblies using file manager , the problem was solved

Comment: Are you deploying all the necessary Assemblies? If you've added a reference from the GAC, it may not be present in the webserver's GAC. Try setting "Copy Local" on the assembly that contains the missing namespace.

Comment: @tomasmcguinness : well I'm copying dlls manually to the server's bin folder. and another point is I'm using website template not webproject , could this be the problem ?

Comment: Is the assmebly that contains that namespace in the Bin folder? .Net won't usually copy a DLL to the Bin if it exists in the GAC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem sometimes is the **ftp client** that is used to deploy files .they corrupt files when uploading them . try uploading files using file manager .